# How to implement Pagination in RecyclerView with retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I have **api call request** with parameters: (page,pageSize:the maximum number of items desired(default 25,Maximum 100.From reddit api documentation)),and i want to use pagination in **RecyclerView**.My data is loading successfully but the problem how do i request to server for the next page.How i can perform pagination with method **addOnScrollListener**

> WebService Class

```
public interface RedditWebService {

    @GET("top.json")
   Observable<Response> getTopPublication(@Query("count")int count, 
                                          @Query("limit")int pageSize);
}
```

> Adapter Class

```
public class RedditAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RedditAdapter.RedditViewHolder> {
    private List<Child> childList;
    private Context context;

    public RedditAdapter(Context context, List<Response.Data.Child> childList) {
        this.childList = childList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RedditViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_layout, parent, false);
        return new RedditViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RedditViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Child child = childList.get(position);
        holder.txtAuthor.setText(child.getmData().getmAuthor());
        String timeAgo = TimeAgo.getTimeAgo(child.getmData().getmCreated());
        Log.d("Time", "" + timeAgo);
        holder.txtDate.setText(timeAgo);
        holder.txtComment.setText(String.format("Comments: %d", child.getmData().getmNumComments()));
        Picasso.get().load(child.getmData().getmThumbnail()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).
                transform(ImageTransformation.getTransformation(holder.imageView)).into(holder.imageView);
        if (!child.getmData().getmThumbnail().equals("")) {
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("extraImage", child.getmData().getmThumbnail());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (childList == null) ? 0 : childList.size();
    }

    public class RedditViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView txtDate, txtAuthor, txtComment;

        public RedditViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            txtDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
            txtAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_author);
            txtComment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comments_num);
        }
    }
}
```

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private RedditAdapter adapter;
    private List<Child> redditList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private int page = 0;
    private int pageSize = 50;


    @Inject
    RedditWebService webService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((BaseApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        fetchData();
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        disposable.add(webService.getTopPublication(page,pageSize)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Response response) throws Exception {
                        adapter = new RedditAdapter(MainActivity.this, response.getData().getChildren());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, throwable.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }));
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly refer this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paging-library-tutorial/, It is done through Retrofit.

Comment: u may want to use PageKeyedDataSource to load next/previous records from the current page. Please check https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PageKeyedDataSource.html. Also refer this tutorial with sample implementation, https://medium.com/@harunwangereka/android-paging-library-with-kotlin-coroutines-b96602e3fae3 . This is Kotlin implementation but should give you fair idea for Java implementation too.

Comment: @KalpeshRupani i will try to write like this tutorial,thank you

Comment: Better luck!! @MohammedQadah

Answer (score 0):

Use EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener.java, it will provide very easy way to do load more call.

Maintain one global variable "page" initialize by 1, and increase it by 1 on every API call or load more call.

```
EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
           @Override
           public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
               // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
               // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
                page++;
               loadMoreCall(page);
           }
      };
```

inside loadMoreCall() you need to add your api call, and after successfull api call, you need to set data to your list and then you need to notify your adaper. thats it only.

reference: https://guides.codepath.com/android/endless-scrolling-with-adapterviews-and-recyclerview

here how to call, api using retrofit:
https://demonuts.com/android-recyclerview-retrofit/

Comment: thanks for ur help but in this tutorial there is no clear code and most of methods are empty

Comment: can you write the whole method please?

Comment: sorry you can follow the https://demonuts.com/android-recyclerview-retrofit/ tutorial.

Comment: i know how to fetch the data by using recyclerview but i want full method of pagination

Comment: @MohammedQadah Any success in this sir?.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the new paging library. Here's a [sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample) and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging). It performs better and you don't have to manually keep track where you are in the scrolling. By following the sample I found it fairly easy to implement this, although it is a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: This sample is too difficult,i don't want to use a lot of libraries,but anyway thank you